# Telepathy broadcaster sends message about how to block telepathy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, telepathy

I'm looking for a short story probably from pre-1985, probably originally published in *Analog*.  A group builds a machine that will be able to broadcast telepathic messages to everyone in the world.  They realize that it will be easy for anyone to build a similar machine leading to chaos (these are not mind-control signals, but being spammed telepathically would still be bad).  They therefore send the first and last telepathic broadcast, which contains easy directions for building a device that will block receipt of any telepathic messages.

*I checked the list of titles for Analog's "Probability Zero" stories (flash fiction, generally humorous) and one possibility is "Mass Communication" by Jay Kay Klein, August 1985. Sounds promising.* (confirmed not to be the right story).

This [USENET](https://groups.google.com/g/rec.arts.sf.written/c/xhqFSQx_eIk/m/V7y5XwPJWlAJ) post is talking about the same story I am, though

> Since broadcast telepathy is the technology you want anyone else to
> have *even less* than nukes (unblockable propaganda... spam...)
> someone puts together a transmitter, transmits the plans for the
> telepathy-blocker, and that's the end of that technology.

Comment: Reminds me of a Phillip K Dick story but that one was about reversing time, not telepathy.

Comment: As a side note, I was surprised at how many results I kept getting on my searches that claimed to be non-fictional guides on how to block unwanted telepathy...

Comment: Same thing happened to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***a short story probably from pre-1985, probably originally published in Analog.***

["The Announcement" by Henry Melton](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49530) is published in *Analog* December 7, 1981.

***A group builds a machine that will be able to broadcast telepathic messages to everyone in the world. They realize that it will be easy for anyone to build a similar machine leading to chaos***

Two research scientists build one. They know others at the conference they attended are almost certain to build one too; they figure that they were only the first to get one working.

They are acutely aware of the hazards of even an eight-second thought being broadcast. Somewhat like our privacy-invading advertisements, but more invasive -- and deadly.

***(these are not mind-control signals, but being spammed telepathically would still be bad).***

> "The broadcast bypasses the sense channels. People have to listen --- because it goes in their thoughts. It would seriously disturb the concentration. Bad luck for a pilot landing a plane."

> "Or a motorist in a tight situation."

> "Or a surgeon with a knife."

> "Bad luck for the patient."

They plan to build the jammer in two days. That is with everything going well in supplies and means.

They discuss, in a concerned mild-mannered argument way, whether to send out one warning telepathic message. They both know the human cost.

One of them rules it out. Not by fiat or hard authority, just a firm refusal.

The other one is the scientist with the ethical dilemma. He stays in the lab after his colleague leaves, thinks about the great harm of broadcasting and about the great harm in not broadcasting any warning.

***They therefore send the first and last                   telepathic broadcast, which contains easy directions for building a device that will block receipt of any telepathic messages.***

He turns the invention on, and announces:

> "This is a world-wide telepathic announcement. Please take notes. This is the design for a jammer against this type of broadcast. Build it quickly...."

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome.